# Want to make one player in my game

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm have made a game which is usually being played by two players.
But now I want to add one player option in it
The game contains 3 stones for each player and each player can move it turn wise
So How can i implement one player option

This is the link of my game

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cognos.crosstone.android

Comment: You can implement a computer opponent with AI.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing input for Player 2, you can add decision-making logic. Think how you would try to win the game. Think of all the different conditions you would consider if you were playing the game. Then every time Player 2's turn comes up, check for same conditions and make a move depending on Player 1's stones.

Make sure your logic doesn't make the computer unbeatable at the end.